# Enabling middle-click and gestures on multitouch clickpad? (Ubuntu 12.04; Samsung NP900X3A-A03US)

Tags: 12.04, multi-touch, trackpad, touchegg

Out of the box (with [the xorg.conf from the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SamsungSeries9#Clickpad)), left-click, right-click, and two-finger scroll all work flawlessly. However, middle-click doesn't work at all (despite appearing to be properly configured in xorg.conf) and Touchegg (compiled from svn) doesn't do anything.

I'm also running the latest Xorg from Ubuntu-X-Swat and kernel 3.5 from kernel-ppa (Quetzal).